# Webhook with Bitbucket and new Azure portal

Tags: azure, bitbucket, continuous-deployment

I've setup a continuous deployment between Bitbucket and the new Azure portal (preview). It works great but when I checked Bitbucket, I noticed that it created a services rather than a webhook but in the service section and the following message is displayed:

`In the future, you will not be able to create POST or Pull Request POST services from this screen, as Bitbucket's new and improved webhooks will replace these services. Existing POST services will continue to function as expected for now. To create a new webhook, refer to  the documentation for Bitbucket's updated webhooks.`

But I can't figure out how to create a webhook in the new Azure Portal. Every articles on the web that I have found are all explaining it based on the old ('current') portal.

Any ideas on how I can create a webhook instead? Not critical since it's working but considering the message displayed in Bitbucket, I thought I'd look into it now rather than wait for bitbucket to disable this feature.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Login to Old Azure Console, https://manage.windowsazure.com
2. Goto Configure
3. Find out DEPLOYMENT TRIGGER URL
4. You can use this trigger URL to setup webhook in BitBucket

But I don't think you have to worry much as Azure will automatically upgrade their services to do this automatically, that is what managed cloud means, we are paying them to manage this.

Comment: I tried it and it seems to have partially worked. When I'm in the new Azure Portal, I use to see an immediate notification that a new push had been made and it was pulling and rebuilding the project but now. I seem to have to click on the "Sync" button in order for the new deployment to occur. Does this mean the new Azure Portal doesn't support setting up and synching webhooks? Anytime I create a new deployment in the new portal, it seems to only create a service rather than webhook. Why is it only building the "project" when clicking on "Sync"? Thanks.

Comment: Nevermind... I've just checked the deployment in the Old Azure portal and it kicks in immediately. I assume it just means that the new portal is not compatible yet with webhooks! Many thanks for this.

Comment: Sorry might have jumped to conclusion to quickly. I've just delete the service entry in BitBucket that was made by the new Azure Portal but now it no longer updates in the old portal. Any ideas? I assumed that if I used webhooks, I wouldn't need the service.

Comment: Ok, deleted the service from Bitbucket and re-create the "integrate deployment" from the old Azure portal and it once again created the service, so no matter what it looks like it needs the service. No this is the part I'm confused about. Why do I need a webhook then??